# Public IP is used when I deploy website on localhost

Tags: linux, cloud

I have got a public IP address. Whenever I deploy any website in `localhost:9000`, the website is also accessible through the `public_ip_address:9000`
I dont want this. Is there a way I can avoid this?
(The port 9000 used is just an example, it happens with every port)

My requirement -
I don't want any website to be accessible directly. Instead it should pass through a reverse proxy(nginx maybe), where I will install certbot to secure it. From nginx I will do a path based routing for multiple websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on a hosted vServer or the likes, there could be two things that are happening here.

1. your server listents not actually on localhost, but on 0.0.0.0:9000 which makes it accessable via every ip routed to that pc.
2. if your server as private ip like 172.16.23.25 (just an example obv) it could be that your server hoster NATs the public IP to your private IP. in this case, if your server listens on that address, it is accessible from the outside, because 172.16.23.25 *is* the outside in a sense.

Comment: Thank you, It is was the second one. I enabled some firewalls. PS: I'm very new to networking, so could not understand